# How to determine in which line of the code a specific mysql table has been altered?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that I am working on . And its huuge really  huge . Is there a way to understand by what line of my php code  a specific mysql table has been altered ?

Comment: Use a text editor and search for the table name?

Comment: the thing is it is remote and huge . and there might be calls for other function that interact with mysql

Comment: What about downloading it first? EditPlus for example has no problem searching huge projects using "Search in files..."

Comment: isnt there a phpy way of doing. The whole project is 8 GB

Comment: Search for any `ALTER` string. And put more time doing your questions. :/

Answer (score 0):

@user1413647 Your question seems to be inexplicit! In order to check the database processes U should look for the query statements within your php code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where in your code it changes something in your database, you have to read through your code - even if it is huge. There is no substitute.

You can accelerate the process by scanning for code that mentions the database name you are concerned about, or the table name or column name if you have that specific information.

Comment: Isnt there a way to scrape php code before it it is processed in the engine ? So I mean grab it before it enters engine.. I thinkg this might help

Comment: You don't have to scrape anything. The php code resides in files on your web server. So just edit the files with a text editor, or search with a searching tool (such as grep). It's a really good idea to understand what your code does, anyway, so reading your code is always helpful.